# Splitting numeric vectors in R

Tags: r

If I have a vector, c(1,2,3,5,7,9,10,12)...and another vector c(3,7,10), how would I produce the following:

```
[[1]]
1,2,3

[[2]]
5,7

[[3]]
9,10

[[4]]
12
```

Notice how 3 7 and 10 become the last number of each list element (except the last one). Or in a sense the "breakpoint". I am sure there is a simple R function I am unknowledgeable of or having loss of memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using `cut` and `split`:

```
split(x, cut(x, c(-Inf, y, Inf)))
#$`(-Inf,3]`
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#$`(3,7]`
#[1] 5 7
#
#$`(7,10]`
#[1]  9 10
#
#$`(10, Inf]`
#[1] 12
```

Comment: Both of you gave pretty much same answer. Although @beginneR generalized it to unsortd vectors too, by using -Inf to Inf as bounds instead of the first and last elements.

Comment: I was just commenting, that our answers are different enough to leave both

Comment: But surprising that there isn't a cool new R function I get to learn today. Just a clever use of split and cut together. :)

Comment: @user41912, You can make your own cool new R function `superCoool <- function(x , y) split(x, cut(x, c(-Inf, y, Inf)))` :)

Comment: @beginneR Genius! Well great answer nonetheless :) Answer accepted.

Comment: Anyway, I've edited it so it will work for unsorted vector too but without having `inf` and `-inf`, so I think it's nicer than your :)

Answer (score 1):

Could do

```
split(x, cut(x, unique(c(y, range(x)))))

## $`[1,3]`
## [1] 1 2 3

## $`(3,7]`
## [1] 5 7

## $`(7,10]`
## [1]  9 10

## $`(10,12]`
## [1] 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @beginneR 's answer, but using `findInterval` instead of `cut`

```
split(x, findInterval(x, y + 1))
# $`0`
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $`1`
# [1] 5 7
# 
# $`2`
# [1]  9 10
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 12
```